# Center of Mass in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was given the following problem and cannot compute the center of mass using cylindrical coordinates. Could anyone explain why my logic is wrong?

A solid has the shape of a right circular cylinder of base radius $r$ and height $h$. Find the center of mass if the density at a point $P$ is proportional to the distance from one of the bases to $P$.

When solving this problem, I realized that each can be written as $P = (r, \theta, z)$ and has density $kz$. Then, I found the mass:

$$\int_{0}^{h}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{r}{kzr \ dr d\theta dz}}} = \frac{k \pi r^2 h^2}{2}$$

When solving this problem with symmetry, I realized that the center of mass must be on the $z$-axis, so I computed $CM_z$:

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{h}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{r}{kz^2r \ dr d\theta dz}}}}{\frac{k \pi r^2 h^2}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}h$$

And therefore the center of mass was $(0, 0, \frac{2}{3}h)$, which is the correct answer. However, when I calculate the center of mass for $r$ and $\theta$, I get the following:

$$CM_{r} = \frac{\int_{0}^{h}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{r}{kzr^2 \ dr d\theta dz}}}}{\frac{k \pi r^2 h^2}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}r$$

$$CM_{\theta} = \frac{\int_{0}^{h}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{r}{kzr \theta \ dr d\theta dz}}}}{\frac{k \pi r^2 h^2}{2}} = \pi$$

which don't match with the correct result. I know that if I find $CM_{x}$ and $CM_{y}$ by substituting in $x = rcos(\theta)$ and $y = rsin(\theta)$ I get the correct answer, but why can I not use the center of mass formula in cylindrical coordinates?